# Cannot resolve all parameters for 'TypeDecorator'(?) .Make sure that typedecarator is decaorated with @injectable

Tags: dependency-injection, angular, inject, angular2-services

I'm getting this error after fixing on how to import folders added to the app.

My app  structure

[image]

My "app.ts" includes

```
import { bootstrap } from "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic";
import { Component,Inject } from "@angular/core";
import {JsonService} from "services";
import {Http,HTTP_PROVIDERS} from "@angular/http";
import {provide} from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'hello-world',
  template: `
  <div>
    Hello world
  </div>
  `,
})
class HelloWorld {
  constructor(@Inject(JsonService) private service :JsonService){

  }
}

bootstrap(HelloWorld,[Http,HTTP_PROVIDERS,JsonService]);
```

my service

```
import {Injectable,Inject} from "@angular/core";
import {Http} from "@angular/http";


    @Injectable
    export class JsonService {
        constructor(@Inject(Http) private http: Http) {

        }

    }
```

my system.js.config  file is as follows

```
 var map = {
    'app':                        'app',
    'rxjs':                       'node_modules/rxjs',
    '@angular':                   'node_modules/@angular',
    'services':                   'services',
    'models':                     'models'
  };

  // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
  var packages = {
    'rxjs': { defaultExtension: 'js' },
     'models':                       { main: 'index.js',  defaultExtension: 'js' },
     'services':                       { main: 'index.js',  defaultExtension: 'js' }
  };

  var packageNames = [
    '@angular/common',
    '@angular/compiler',
    '@angular/core',
    '@angular/http',
    '@angular/platform-browser',
    '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',
    '@angular/router',
    '@angular/router-deprecated',
    '@angular/testing',
    '@angular/upgrade',
    'services',
    'models'
  ];
```

at the first i got 404 error that my services is missing after modifying the system.js and adding services an models ,i am getting this error

still getting this 404

[image]

Error: Cannot resolve all parameters for 'TypeDecorator'(?). Make sure that all the parameters are decorated with Inject or have valid type annotations and that 'TypeDecorator' is decorated with Injectable

link to complete code https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ai1EHDfZ96E2wij-MtwLHdCI-hVI

Answer (score 0):

What resolved that error for me was the comment by JGW96 in [this thread](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/7221) that in Angular 2 you cannot inject a service into a service. I was creating a view module for some JSON data and had split the subscription off into a view module. Once I moved it back to the main service module, and then included that main service as a provider in the view component, the decorator error resolved.